# Where SHOULD protocols be declared in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

As far as best practices go, where should a protocol be declared? within the related class or in its own separate file?

Either way would work in theory, but are there any reasons to steer one way or another?

Comment: What do you mean by "related class"?

Comment: good question! The class that will be calling on it. e.g. `someInstance.someDelegateMethod()`

Comment: So you're specifically talking about a _delegate_ protocol?

Comment: yes sir! that is what i mean

Comment: Can you edit your question to be more specific, then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I follow a rule of keeping the delegate protocol within the file of the class that contains the delegate property.

The following code outline illustrates keeping the protocol with the property where the delegate will be set.

**MyClass.swift:**

```
protocol MyDelegate: class {
    func firstDelegateMethod() 
    func secondDelegateMethod() 
}

class MyClass {
    weak var delegate: MyDelegate?  
}
```

The delegates are the objects that need to conform to the protocol and are defined by other classes, not the one containing the protocol.

It's helpful to remember that the delegates are the ones doing the work. They do what is needed by what is declared in the protocol.

It can be confusing to keep track of these relationships since the protocol can essentially be placed anywhere. If you follow a *consistent* pattern like this it will make life easier and your code more manageable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel! This makes sense to me, unless you are using that protocol in more than one place. In such case I guess it makes sense to place it in a separate class. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad it helped @JulianB. And yes having a separate class is a good option when sharing the protocol among multiple classes.